# Error when trying to create an object of my class Solution()

Tags: python, object

Hello I am new with python object oriented programming and i am struggling to figure out how to define an instance of my class

Here is what i am trying to do:

```
class Solution(object):
    s = Solution()
```

but it seems to be underlined red in my IDE can anyone show me the correct way and explain what my problem is

Thanks

Comment: You should finish your tutorials first. Stack Overflow is not intended to be a replacement for tutorials. It's not clear what you want to do: if you want to create an empty class and make an instance of it, that is usually covered in step 1 of any basic python-OOP tutorial

Answer (score 2):

You need some content underneath the class definition, even if it's only a `pass` statement:

```
class Solution(object):
    pass

s = Solution()
```

Comment: is there no way of me to declare the object `s` within the class Solution so like

`class Solution(object):
    pass

    s = Solution()`

Answer (score 2):

That’s because you have not defined the class. You need to define the class first. Then you’ll be able to create an instance.

```
    class Solution:
        #define the class
    s = Solution()
```

Answer (score 1):

You must have something in the class or else there is going to be a syntax error. If you don't need anything in the class just put pass. Example:

```
class Solution(object):
    pass

s = Solution()
```

Pass doesn't do anything, it serves as a placeholder for future code to avoid these errors.